# AngularJS: ngMessage weird behavior with input with type "email"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, validation, html-input

I follow [Moving from ngModel.$parsers /ng-if to ngModel.$validators /ngMessages](http://toddmotto.com/moving-from-ng-model-parsers-to-ng-model-validates-ng-messages/) article from [Todd Motto's blog](http://toddmotto.com/) and I want to migrate from `ng-if` to `ng-messages`. But `ng-messages` directive behaves very weird when I try to display to user two different messages for `<input type="email">`: first, when user leave field empty (then `required` error occurs) and second, when format is wrong (then `email` error occurs) - it displays both `required` and `mail` messages, but my old code displays only one message - about `required` error - and that is I think welcomed behavior. Here is simplified code:

```
<form name="ngMessageMailForm">
  <input type="email" required="" name="email" ng-model="ctrl.ngMessageMail" />
  <div ng-messages="ngMessageMailForm.email.$error" ng-if="ngMessageMailForm.email.$touched">
    <span ng-message="email">
      E-mail has not proper format<br />
    </span>
    <span ng-message="required">
      E-mail is required<br />
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comparison between old and new code you can find in this Plunker: [Ng-if vs ng-messages at plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nr5Z6l4J3tPuefd5NigW?p=preview), to reproduce weird behavior of `ng-message` click inside and then outside of mail inputs. You will see one message in case of `ng-if` form, and two messages in case of `ng-message` form.
Did I miss something while migrating from `ng-if` to `ng-messages`? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine but you miss to add [angular-messages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) library to your project...

Add its files to your project and inject `ngMessages` to your angularjs module then you are good to go...

[here is update plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LhkMHRGiTBxVdeYLnkbs?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much - indeed I forgot to include it, now it works like a charm :)