# Angular Form Validation: $error.required set even when ng-required=false with custom input directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-validation, ng-messages

I have [Custom input component with validation](https://plnkr.co/edit/szX39i1rNmsmrlKa42h4?p=preview) with [ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages),[FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) and ng-required:

```html
<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <input
      id="{{$ctrl.fieldName}}"
      name="{{$ctrl.fieldName}}"
      class="form-control"
      type="text"
      minlength="{{$ctrl.minLength}}"
      maxlength="{{$ctrl.maxLength}}"
      ng-required="{{$ctrl.isRequired === 'true'}}"
      ng-model="$ctrl.value"
      ng-change="$ctrl.form.$submitted = false;"
  >
    <div 
      ng-messages="$ctrl.form[$ctrl.fieldName].$error"
      ng-if="$ctrl.form.$submitted"
    >
      <span class="help-block" ng-message="required">
        Field is required
      </span>
      <span class="help-block" ng-message="minlength">
        Minimum length of field: {{$ctrl.minLength}}
      </span>
      <span class="help-block" ng-message="maxlength">
        Maximum length of field: {{$ctrl.maxLength}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Which is used in this way:

```html
<act-text-field 
  form="heroAddForm" 
  field-name="name" 
  min-length="3" 
  max-length="15" 
  is-required="true" 
  errors="$ctrl.errors.name" 
  ng-model="$ctrl.hero.name">
</act-text-field>
```

What I want to achieve is validation fires when user clicks `submit` button. And it works, validation fires also for required field `name`, but also for field `description` which is not required:

```html
<act-text-field 
  form="heroAddForm" 
  field-name="description" 
  max-length="50" 
  is-required="false" 
  errors="$ctrl.errors.description" 
  ng-model="$ctrl.hero.description"
></act-text-field>
```

Also for this field validation messages are visible, although field `description` is valid, cause I add class `has-error` to invalid fields:

```html
<div class="form-group"
  ng-class="{'has-error': $ctrl.form.$submitted && (!$ctrl.form[$ctrl.fieldName].$valid)}" 
>
<!-- rest of code -->
```

You can easily reproduced this wrong behaviour in my [Plunker: Custom input demo app with validation states](https://plnkr.co/edit/szX39i1rNmsmrlKa42h4?p=preview) (I know it has other mistakes). I think `ng-message="required"` should not be visible, because field `description` is not required. I know I can add some `ng-if`s to code to by-pass it, but I think I make a mistake somewhere which I can't see. Do you see where I made a mistake? Thank you in advance for every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, [again I forgot to include ngMessages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34253093/3368498). Without it, my code went crazy, I apologize for wasting your time :)